Total energy for isolated atoms in VASP
To calculate cohesive energy, I am doing the total energy calculation for isolated atoms Fe, N, C, Mn, Ti. I have considered a large cubic system of 15A where the atom lies at the centre. N and C scf calculation converged well but Fe, Mn, and Ti scf calculations are not converging even at 500 iterations. I tried with ISPIN=2 i.e. spin polarized calculation then all are converged however the energy differs highly. for example without ISPIN Nitrogen's total energy is -0.08797249 but with ISPIN it is -3.11714740. I am confused about which energy should be used.

+1 but can you please make a more precise title?
